# Can I use a link to Ressource in Json?

Tags: json

Hello I want to create a link in Json to other Json files, that are in my Ressource folder.
Can I do that? How?

example:

```
{
"name": "Category 1",
"linkToJson": R.Ressources.Categories1
}
```

I want to use it in Android Studio. I have a main category and sub-categories. There will be so many sub-categories, so I want to separate them into individual files.

Comment: No. JSON does not support that.

Comment: You could instead try to store the name of the json file you want to "link" to, so that you can load it based on that

Comment: Thanks but If i store it to a string, how can I convert it later to a ressource file?